# MySQL syntax error when creating a table with 2 foreign keys as primary key

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

I keep getting a 1064 error when I run the below query but I don't understand what's wrong with it:

```
CREATE TABLE hashmkb_mangatracker.group_release
(
 group_id int NOT NULL,
 release_id int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (group_id, release_id),
 UNIQUE INDEX (release_id, group_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES group(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (release_id) REFERENCES release(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

The error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group(id),
FOREIGN KEY (release_id) REFERENCES release(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB' at line 7
```

Appreciate the help.

Comment: `group` is a reserved word and you need to backtick ` ` it.

Comment: That was it. Can' believe it was that simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GROUP is a reserved keyword in MySql.
The same goes for RELEASE.
You will have to add backticks around those like this:

```
CREATE TABLE hashmkb_mangatracker.group_release
(
 group_id int NOT NULL,
 release_id int NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (group_id, release_id),
 UNIQUE INDEX (release_id, group_id),
 FOREIGN KEY (group_id) REFERENCES `group`(id),
 FOREIGN KEY (release_id) REFERENCES `release`(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Here is a list of all reserved words: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html